# Query resource quota for PostgreSQL accounts

Tags: postgresql

Within the latest (12, 13) versions of PostgreSQL, is there any throttling support on the user-account level, to limit how much data any query can produce and/or how much time + memory it may consume under that user account?

I want to limit specific user accounts to allow up to certain amount of data and/or time to consume within the server, before erroring with "query quota exceeded" or something like that.

**Example**

I want to configure user account `guest` to produce "quota exceeded" failure for any query that returns more than 10kb of data or takes more than 10 seconds to execute.

Comment: No, there is no such feature in Postgres. The only way you could get a filesystem quota is to use a tablespace on a really small disk and assign that to the guest user.

Comment: I suppose that means I would have to provide extra `LIMIT` logic for each query to implement the data size requirements. But as for the timing requirements, is there anything usable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support for resource quotas in PostgreSQL.

Your best bet is `statement_timeout`:

```
ALTER ROLE baduser SET statement_timeout = '10s';
```

You cannot limit the number of rows returned, but perhaps `statement_timeout` is good enough.